# Is it possible to change powers without pausing?

Tags: ps4, mega-man-legacy-collection

Is it possible to cycle through Megaman's powers without pausing the game in MegaMan Legacy Collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately this is **not possible** in the games in Mega Man Legacy Collection. These games aren't just recreations of the original games, but actual emulations of the original code. As such, if it wasn't in the original games, it isn't in the Legacy Collection. (The challenges are apparently the result of some particularly clever coding.)

Unfortunately the ability to change the the weapons on the fly was added to the series after Mega Man 6, the last game in the Legacy Collection. (Can't quite remember which was the first to have it.)

Comment: Quick swapping was available in other versions of the game like the Mega Man Anniversary Collection, Rockman Complete Works, and this [Mega Man 3 romhack](https://www.romhacking.net/hacks/2243/).